# How do I display rows from a max count?

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I want to return all the data, from max count query with hospital that has most number of patients.  What I seem to be getting when I try to nest queries is display of all rows of hospital data.  I've tried to look at similar questions in stack overflow and other sites it seems to be a simple query to do but i am not getting it.

```
select max(highest_hospital) as max_hospital
from (select count(hospital) as highest_hospital
from doctor
group by hospital)

highest_hospital
-------------
            3
```

```
Doc ID  Doctor           Patient               Hospital    Medicine   Cost
------ -------           ------            ---------      ------     --------
1      Jim Bob         Patient1             Town 1        Medicine 1   4000
2      Janice Smith    Patient2             Town 2        Medicine 3    3000
3      Harold Brown    Patient3             Town 2        Medicine 5    2000
4      Larry  Owens    Patient4             Town 2        Medicine 6    3000
5      Sally Brown     Patient5             Town 3        Medicine 7    4000
6      Bob Jim         Patient6             Town 4        Medicine 8     6000
```

Outcome should be return of 3 rows

```
Doc ID  Doctor           Patient               Hospital    Medicine   Cost
------ -------           ------            ---------      ------     --------
2      Janice Smith    Patient2             Town 2        Medicine 3    3000
3      Harold Brown    Patient3             Town 2        Medicine 5    2000
4      Larry  Owens    Patient4             Town 2        Medicine 6    3000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use window functions:

```
select d.*
from (select d.*, max(hospital_count) over () as max_hospital_count
      from (select d.*, count(*) over (partition by hospital) as hospital_count
            from doctor d
           ) d
     ) d
where hospital_count = max_hospital_count;
```

Edit:

Using `GROUP BY` is a pain.  If you are only looking for a single hospital (even when there are ties), then in Oracle 12C you can do:

```
select d.*
from doctor d
where d.hospital = (select d2.hospital
                    from doctor d2
                    group by d2.hospital
                    order by count(*) desc
                    fetch first 1 row only
                   );
```

You can do this in earlier versions of Oracle using an additional subquery.

Comment: it does work thank you.  Is their any alternative solutions other than using  windows functions?  I was trying to use group by but was not getting the intended results.